# Sorting an array / a variable by first letter in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

How can you sort the following word by the given rule?

Example data is `saapas` which I want to be either

```
aaapss
```

or in the array

```
s
a
a
p
a
s
```

and then somehow

```
a
a
a
p
s
s
```

The function `arsort` with `sort_flags` SORT_REQULAR and SORT_STRING did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original post you said either a string or an array.  eyze's solution works for the string but sort() will work for the array of values:

```
$array = array('s', 'a', 'a', 'p', 'a', 's');
sort($array);

//will output
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => a
    [2] => a
    [3] => p
    [4] => s
    [5] => s
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'saapas';
$string = str_split($string, 1);
sort($string);
echo implode('', $string);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = 'saapas';
echo implode(sort(str_split($string, 1)));
```